# Get non-over lapping area of two rectangles

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

How can I get the "Polygon" or "Region" of the non-over lapping area of two rectangles.

Like (A-B), where "A" and "B" are rectangles. We can easily get the intersecting rectangle using the Rectangle.Intersect method but I want the part of a rectangle that is not common.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Rectangle a, b;

var region = new Region(a);
region.Exclude(b);
```

[Region.Exclude(Rectangle rect) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0zcf43ae.aspx)

Comment: Isn't that "A \ B"  rather than "(A ∪ B) \ (A ∩ B)"?

Comment: or you can use [Region.Xor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15sdft5d.aspx) if you want the non-common part of _both_ rectangles.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the intersection of two rectangles using `Intersect`.  That means that you can get the area of the intersection.  So, take the area of the intersection multiplied by two (multiplied by two because it occupies the same area over both rectangles) and subtract it from the sum of the total area of the two rectangles.